# playing a video should stop all other videos in html, angular application

Tags: html, angular, html5-video

I have an Angular application and am loading some videos with html5 video tags, I need for only one video to play at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I did it in **Angular2 app**.

1. In the component HTML, bind an event `(playing)="onPlayingVideo($event)"` so later in the class component you can handle the logic.

```html
    `<div *ngFor='let video of videoList; let i=index' class="video">
        <div class="video_player">
            <video (playing)="onPlayingVideo($event)" controls>
                <source src="{{video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2. In the component class: define a property to save the current playing video `currentPlayingVideo: HTMLVideoElement;`. and define your event listener method where you will handle the logic in my case i called it `onPlayingVideo(event)`. Simply, each time a user plays a new video, just pause the old video and play the new selected one. So your class should look like the following:

```js
        export class VideoListComponent implements OnInit {
            
            currentPlayingVideo: HTMLVideoElement;
            
            constructor() { }
            ngOnInit() { }
            
            onPlayingVideo(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // play the first video that is chosen by the user
                if (this.currentPlayingVideo === undefined) {
                    this.currentPlayingVideo = event.target;
                    this.currentPlayingVideo.play();
                } else {
                // if the user plays a new video, pause the last 
                // one and play the new one
                    if (event.target !== this.currentPlayingVideo) {
                        this.currentPlayingVideo.pause();
                        this.currentPlayingVideo = event.target;
                        this.currentPlayingVideo.play();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope that was clear :)

thanks,
Fadi